# Rails - Submit form in iFrame when model is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, iframe

I'm trying to use Yodlee's API which requires the submission of a form and use of an iFrame.

How would I have the form submit and load in an iFrame automatically when a user loads the  model?  Here is the initial (unworking) code that I have:

```
%myModal_fastlink.modal
  %label{:for => "modal-1"}
    %li Add Portfolio
  %input#modal-1.modal-state{:type => "checkbox"}/
  .modal-fade-screen
    .modal-inner
      .modal-close{:for => "modal-1"}
      %iframe{:height => "100%", :name => "an_iframe", :src => "https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/", :width => "100%"}

%br
%form#rsessionPost{:action => "https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/", :method => "POST", target: "an_iframe"}
  %input{name: "app", type: "hidden", value: "10003100"}
  %input{name: "rsession", type: "hidden", value: current_user.yodlee.fastlink.rsession}
  %input{name: "token", type: "hidden", value: current_user.yodlee.fastlink.token}
  %input{name: "redirectReq", type: "hidden", value: "true"}
:javascript
  function launch() {
    $("#myModal_fastlink").modal();
    document.getElementById('rsessionPost').submit();

  }
  $("#myModal_fastlink .btn-close").click(function() {
    $("#myModal_fastlink").modal('toggle');
  });
```

Comment: Can you please share reference to ` Yodlee's API which requires the submission of a form and use of an iFrame`?

Comment: @AmitPatel  - Here's the Yodlee API documentation for Fastlink. Happy to answer any questions to save time. https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0/FastLink_Integration_Guide_for_Web.

Comment: @AmitPatel - Here's a working example with PHP - https://github.com/seansparx/wealthfund/blob/91dcb62130c05a29fb1554af54011afcce4a2965/account/application/views/popups/fastlink.php